# Цвет меню в Android

Tags: menu, android

Как изменить цвет меню из белого в черное, что бы на всех экранах оно было черным например, или зафиксировать так что бы на всех экранах оно было белое.

Я говорю про вот такое меню:

[image].

Вот ссылка на [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: откатиться на старую прошивку? Или собрать себе кастомную.

Comment: мне в программе нужно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

смотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719173/change-background-color-of-android-menu)